# Multithreaded program doesn't update a global array as expected

Tags: c++

So what I want to do is for each thread to update the global array,but it seems to be failing.

Code:
    #include
    #include
    #include
    using namespace std;
    int max[10][3];

```
#define randnum(min,max) ((rand()%(max-min+1))+min) //  [ min , max ] 

HANDLE mutex = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL);

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID lpParamter)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
    int* a = (int*)lpParamter;
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        max[a[0]][i] = randnum(1, 10);
    }
    ReleaseSemaphore(mutex, 1, NULL);

    return 0L;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    HANDLE hThread[10];
    int a[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        hThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThread, a+i, 0, NULL);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(10, hThread, true, INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << max[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
2       8       5
```

Why does the array have the same values?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One problem is that our code is *serial* not parallel. Because the first thing you do in the thread function is to lock the mutex, and you release it the last thing you do, the first thread that locks the mutex will run until it's finished before any othe rthread can grab the mutex (and in turn run until finish before letting the next thread run, etc.).

Comment: Actually, since no thread (in your current code) will access the same memory, you don't actually need a mutex for that. But you *do* need it for the `rand` function call, as it handles global state. You might want to learn about [the standard C++ random-number facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which can help you drop the mutex completely. And I also recommend you learn about [the C++ standard thread facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (like [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)).

Comment: Lastly a hint about creating multi-threaded programs: First write it without any threads at all! Make sure that everything works as it should before adding threads into the mix. And with `std::thread` it's very easy to create a simple function to do what you need to do, and just call it like any other function. Then when you want to add threads you create one or more `std::thread` object using the function.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your question. Also, there are a few things off that don't directly cause bugs, so once you have it running, file it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, you failed to reduce your code to a [mcve], which would quickly have shown you the problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].